# Как из дней сделать дату

Tags: python

Есть база данных, где дата рождения указана в формате -4567 дней от сегодня. Как преобразовать все такие данные в колонке в нормальную дату?

Comment: Зависит от базы данных. Если это SQL база, то сделать запрос который вычтет из сегодняшней даты нужное кол-во дней. Например на postgresql он мог бы выглядеть так `update table set birth_date = now() - make_interval(days=>birth_days)`. Детали в каждой БД будут незначительно отличаться. Делать это на питоне дороже и по времени разработки и по времени выполнения. Но если все таки хочется, то сделать цикл читающий записи из БД, вычисляющий дату через timedelta и записывающий обратно в БД

Comment: Тут не совсем полный вопрос. Не совсем понятно вы хотите поменять данные в базе? тогда какая база. Если вы просто хотите полученые данные из базы преобразовать и вывести куда то?

Answer (score 4):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

birthday = -4567
d = datetime.today() + timedelta(days = birthday)

print(d)
```

Пример - https://www.online-python.com/68xMUYmKwI